# Settings.cs appears as a separate file after moving a project to a different folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I tried to move a project from one folder to another following [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s advice:

> Remove the project from your solution by right-clicking it in the
>   Solution Explorer window and choosing Remove. Move the entire project
>   folder, including subdirectories wherever you want it to go. Add the
>   project back to your solution.

After doing it, suddenly, a "Settings.cs" file appears in the solution, even though there is already a "Settings.settings" file under "Properties":

[image: Solution Explorer]

Also, when entering "Settings.settings" and pressing F7 ("View Code"), "Settings.cs" is opened.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I have done is deleting both "Settings.settings" and "Settings.cs". Then I created a new "Settings.settings" file, and the problem is solved: There is a "Settings.settings" file, but the "Settings.cs" file is hidden.

Noted that if you have any settings in the file, you should keep a backup to restore the settings later in the process.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. Settings.cs is what allows you to save/change settings in your application through your application itself, instead of manually prior to building/running the project. It is auto-generated by your Settings.settings file. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: But it wasn't there before I moved the project.

Comment: It's auto-generated from Settings.settings. It's supposed to be there. This isn't an error, or a problem. There is nothing to fix. Read the comments in the file, it explains exactly what it is there for.

Comment: If it bothers you and you don't care for updating the settings during run time, right click and then delete it.

Comment: I tried it, but every time I recompile, it is generated again.

Comment: It's auto-generated. It's supposed to be there. You won't be able to get rid of it permanently. Why are you getting so caught up on something that doesn't affect your project in any way?

Comment: I know it is auto-generated. But it wasn't before. This is a file I never use and I *hate* seeing it on my solution explorer.